# Can't resolve latest Quarkus plugin

Tags: java, maven, gradle, quarkus

I've been attempting to update to the latest Quarkus (`1.2.0.CR1`) version, and it can't resolve the plugin artifact from Maven:

```
A problem occurred configuring project ':WebServer:Server'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':WebServer:Server:classpath'.
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-gradle-plugin:1.2.0.CR1.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/gstewart/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-gradle-plugin/1.2.0.CR1/quarkus-gradle-plugin-1.2.0.CR1.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-gradle-plugin/1.2.0.CR1/quarkus-gradle-plugin-1.2.0.CR1.pom
       - https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/io/quarkus/quarkus-gradle-plugin/1.2.0.CR1/quarkus-gradle-plugin-1.2.0.CR1.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/quarkus/quarkus-gradle-plugin/1.2.0.CR1/quarkus-gradle-plugin-1.2.0.CR1.pom
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
```

When following the link directly I get a 404, but really unsure how else to configure things to fix this.

I've been using Quarkus with Gradle, and the latest plugin version that I can resolve is `1.0.1.Final`. I'm using Gradle version `6.1`. To be clear, it seems that I can resolve different versions of actual Quarkus just fine, it is just the Gradle plugin itself that seems to have issues.

Project organization:

```
build.gradle
gradle.properties
settings.gradle
...
webserver/
    ...
    server/
        build.gradle
        gradle.properties
```

gradle.properties:

```
quarkusPluginVersion=1.0.1.Final
```

settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'io.quarkus' version "${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}

...
```

webserver/server/gradle.properties:

```
quarkusPlatformVersion=1.2.0.CR1
quarkusPlatformArtifactId=quarkus-universe-bom
quarkusPlatformGroupId=io.quarkus
```

webserver/server/build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.quarkus:quarkus-gradle-plugin:${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "4.1.5"
    id 'io.quarkus'
}
...
```

Update:

Noticing that there aren't any new versions of the plugin since `1.0.1.Final` ([maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.quarkus/quarkus-gradle-plugin))... which would explain the issues seen. Can anyone more in the know comment? Is this expected or an oversight somewhere?

Update 2:

Thanks for the hints guys. However, after following the migration guide (and moving to `1.2.0.Final`), I am now having an issue where none of the quarkus dependencies are found...

```
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':WebServer:Server:compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-universe-bom:1.2.0.Final.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - file:/home/gstewart/.m2/repository/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom/1.2.0.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-1.2.0.Final.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom/1.2.0.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-1.2.0.Final.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/quarkus/quarkus-universe-bom/1.2.0.Final/quarkus-universe-bom-1.2.0.Final.pom
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml:.
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-mailer:.
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson:.
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi:.
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler:.
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-mongodb-client:.
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
   > Could not find io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy:.
     Required by:
         project :WebServer:Server
```

updated settings.gradle:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
    plugins {
        id 'io.quarkus' version "${quarkusPluginVersion}"
    }
}
...
```

updated webserver/server/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "4.1.5"
    id 'io.quarkus'
}
...

dependencies {
    compile project(":BaseCode:Core")
    compile project(":BaseCode:ManagerIO")
    compile project(":BaseCode:Stats")
    compile project(":WebServer:WebLibrary")

    implementation enforcedPlatform("${quarkusPlatformGroupId}:${quarkusPlatformArtifactId}:${quarkusPlatformVersion}")
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-config-yaml'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-mailer'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy-jackson'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-smallrye-openapi'
    implementation 'io.quarkus:quarkus-scheduler'
    ...
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you've checked Maven Central, but after 1.0.1.Final, Quarkus Gradle Plugin is published on Gradle Plugin portal site (Gradle - Plugin: io.quarkus (https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/io.quarkus )

Comment: I'm not sure, but your `webserver/server/` has `settings.gradle` ? Like your root project directory, you need to add `settings.gradle` in your `webserver/server/`, in my opinion.

Comment: @tkhm I thought at one point I saw that only the root was allowed to have a `settings.gradle`? Has that changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We changed a lot of things in how the Gradle plugin works in 1.1.

Please refer to the 1.1 migration guide for all the details about how to configure your Gradle project: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/wiki/Migration-Guide-1.1#gradle-plugin .

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Though I now seem to have another issue where none of the dependencies are found... see the new update

Comment: You have to use the `quarkus-bom` for now, if you want to use 1.2.0.Final. I haven't released the `quarkus-universe-bom` yet. It will be released early next week. See my answer here for the details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59880235/how-to-update-the-quarkus-version-used/59881264#59881264 .

Comment: Thanks! Using `quarkus-bom` worked. Any big difference between that and the universe one?

Comment: The `quarkus-bom` doesn't have the Camel Quarkus extensions. It's just the core ones. The idea behind the universe is to have a consistent ecosystem of external extensions.