# How to update the quarkus version used

Tags: java, quarkus

What is the recommended way of upgrading the quarkus version used in an existing application?

I have taken a look at my pom.xml, since the quarkus extensions dont specify the version used, I assume that they will get updated based on the main quarkus version.
The properties which look to be relevant in the update are quarkus-plugin.version, quarkus.platform.group-id and surefire-plugin.version.
How can I decide which ones to change, and is there anything else to be aware of?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nowadays, the easiest way to update Quarkus is to install the [Quarkus CLI](https://quarkus.io/guides/cli-tooling).

Then you can update your Quarkus application with `quarkus update`.

You can find more details about `quarkus update` here: https://quarkus.io/guides/update-quarkus .

---

*The following is still true but usability has been improved a lot since then. I kept the content below as it is informative.*

There is one important thing to know, we have:

- Quarkus Core: this is the main Quarkus artifacts + all the core extensions: the quarkus-bom is the one of Core. The Quarkus Maven plugin is part of it too.
- Quarkus Platform: it contains more extensions such as Camel Quarkus: the quarkus-universe-bom is the one from the Platform, it contains the Core + the additional extensions

We usually release Quarkus core then Quarkus Platform with a few days between the two as we often need a release of Camel Quarkus, which is an Apache project and organizes a 72 hours vote for each release.

In a newly created project, you have the following properties:

```
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.1.1.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.1.1.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
```

- `quarkus-plugin.version` is the version of the Quarkus Maven plugin, it should be in line with the version of the core you use
- `quarkus.platform.artifact-id` can right now either be `quarkus-universe-bom` for the whole Platform or just `quarkus-bom` for the Core only.
- `quarkus.platform.version` is the version of the BOM.

Usually all these versions should be aligned. But... it could happen that we would need some quick update in the Platform and not of the core and we could then only release a new version of the platform. This hasn't happened yet to be honest.

Let's take an example of what happened today: I released Quarkus Core 1.2.0.Final but we are still waiting for Camel Quarkus to be released to release the Platform.

If you want to update early, you can change the BOM to use the `quarkus-bom` and update everything to 1.2.0.Final.

Or you can wait for the Platform to be released early next week and stay on the Platform `quarkus-universe-bom`.

We also only update the website documentation and code.quarkus.io when the full Platform is released.

Comment: Why is this not in the documentation / guides?

Answer (score 1):

It used to work to simply issue the command

```
mvn io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:1.4.2.Final:create
```

in the base project directory for it to automatically update the Quarkus versions in the project `pom.xml` file, but since `1.6.0.Final` it errors:

> project XXXXX: Unable to generate the project in a directory that already contains a pom.xml -> [Help 1]

I will create an improvement suggestion ticket at Quarkus to restore this functionality, maybe with a dedicated maven goal (like `update`)

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer might come in late, but there is a dedicated section to upgrading Quarkus in the docs now:

https://quarkus.io/guides/update-quarkus

Most importantly, you can use the Quarkus CLI tool, or a Maven plugin, to upgrade Quarkus now, which came in handy, when migrating from 2.x to 3.x.

```bash
# Quarkus CLI Tool
quarkus update
```

or

```bash
# Quarkus Maven Plugin
./mvnw io.quarkus.platform:quarkus-maven-plugin:3.2.3.Final:update -N
```

The Quarkus team also provides a migration guide for each version, which you should check before executing the upgrade.